# Exception Handleling

Tags: java, exception, io

Is it possible to catch an exception outside of the method that throws it ?

For the example:

```
public double[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException
    {
    File inFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
    try
    {
        readData(in);
        return data;
    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

How would I go about catching the **IOException** in the `main` method?
Can I just do `catch(IOException){}` ?

Comment: Sure, if the method doesn't catch the Exception by itself, it is propagated to the caller .

Comment: Or you can `catch` it, then rethrow it (in the catch block) so the caller gets it as well. But **never** have your catch blocks empty :)

Comment: How do you rethrow an exception? Is it the same as just throwing it but with in the catch ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes tou can do that catching the exception throwed in the `someMethod()` method like this:

```
   public double[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException
    {
    ...
    }
```

In another method ex:

```
  public void someMethod(){
   try
    {
   readFile(in);
   return data;
    }catch(IOException io){
   }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `try/catch` statement in this method, since you don't want the exception to be handled inside, you want it to be thrown. (that's what the `throws` keyword does)

So you can just do this:

```
public double[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    File inFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);

    readData(in);
    // If everything goes normally, the execution flow shall pass on to
    // the next statements, otherwise if an IOException is thrown, it shall
    // be handled by the caller method (main)

    in.close();
    return data;
}
```

& inside your `main` method, handle the potential exception:

```
try {
    double[] result = readFile("filename.ext");
    // ...
}
catch(IOException e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Comment: Much better, that is what I was looking for!